# Como traduzir o Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]clonei esse repositório  https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang.git com pacote de linguagens para o Laravel, copiei a pasta pt-BR para resources/lang, alterei o locale e fallback_locale para pt-BR, porém minha página não foi traduzida, só as mensagens de validação!

[image: Alterações para tradução do Idioma]

Comment: Porque essa tradução que você provocou no seu código só server para validação, paginação, passwords e auth ... o resto não é realmente traduzido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse pacote padrão traduz somente as validações e mensagens geradas pelo laravel.

As mensagens de blade não são traduzidas por padrão, você também tem que preparar sua blade para ser traduzida.

olha aqui na documentação que vai te esclarecer melhor
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

Answer (score 3):

Criei uma conta só para responder corretamente (visto que mais de 2000 pessoas já viram esta pergunta). Na verdade, o problema aí foi muito simples: o pacote vem com a pasta "pt_BR" (com underline e BR maiúsculo). O arquivo json na pasta "resources/lang" deve estar nomeado exatamente como está no arquivo "config/app.php". No seu caso (e no meu) "pt-br". Com traço e tudo minusculo.
Se encontrar alguma outra linha não traduzida, basta adicionar ao arquivo json seguindo a mesma formatação.

Answer (score 2):

Eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

- Alterei no arquivo app.php as configurações conforme abaixo:
  'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo',
  'locale' => 'pt-BR',
  'fallback_locale' => 'pt-BR',
- Criei uma cópia da pasta en (que está dentro de lang) e renomeei para pt-BR
- Limpei o arquivo de configuração com o comando: php artisan config:clear

A partir daí as traduções nas validações de campo funcionaram.